# Do I need to revalidate my Bing Maps credentials?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

Do Bing Maps credentials time out?

My Bing Maps credentials, supplied like so (but with a bogus value shown here):

```
<maps:Map x:Name="bingMap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LandmarkTapped="BingMap_OnLandmarkTapped" Credentials="jkdfsjkfadjkdfsajkdfsasdfaasdf" />
```

...have worked fine until today, and now I get this message across the map on my main page when I run my app:

"*The specified credentials are invalid. You can sign up...(bla bla bla)*"

So does one need to "re-sign up" for Bing Maps credentials every once in a while, or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials are valid for a specific period depending on the type of license (key) you're using. There are several type of license like trial (expires after 90 day period), Windows Store App key type...

Also, keep in mind that you have associated limitations regarding the number of transactions that you can make and requests you can do on Bing Maps platform that apply differently varying on the license key.

For more information, take a look at the MSDN documentation: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

If you need to update your key, you should connect to the Bing Maps developer portal: http://bingmapsportal.com where you should have the possibility to update the key in the appropriate type. You can also contact Microsoft through the form: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/contact.aspx

Comment: Thanks; it's a Trial Windows Store app key - I'd forgotten it was a trial. Rant: All this updating of trials, having to constantly download updates do libraries, etc., is a real productivity drain. It would be better if these took place in the background, or at least just a prompt for them: "Do you want to update extension/tool/etc. ABC?"

Comment: It turns out that there is a Basic/Windows 8 app key that can be acquired (not a Trial), from https://www.bingmapsportal.com/. I got one for each of my two current apps.