# Invalid credentials after creating a key for a BingMap control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I would like to use BingMap in C#.

I have created a WPF project and used BingMap  by adding `Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF`.

I have also created a key at https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application#

But, when I ran the WPF project, I got error:

```
invalid credential. sign up for a developer account at maicrosoft.com/maps/developers
```

Then I created a new key and it worked. After about one hour, I got the same error.

This is my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="draw_a_map.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="<my key>" Margin="0,0,0,-10"/>
</Grid>
```

The solutions at

- [Do I need to revalidate my Bing Maps credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299569/do-i-need-to-revalidate-my-bing-maps-credentials)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37ecc085-82b9-48af-af69-cb5b0fb2562e/invalid-credential-sign-up-for-a-developer-account-from-bing-map-wpf?forum=silverlightnet

do not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your key works fine for me. You should definitely not publish it here, because anybody can (ab)use it.

Comment: I have created a new key but still does not work fo me.